# How many hamiltonian circles are there in $K_{n,n}$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I've got this question in a quiz. How many hamiltonian circles are there in $K_{n,n}$?

Well, Looking at how $K_{n,n}$ is built, I have $n$ options to choose a vertex in 1 'side' of the graph. I'll have $n$ options, then i need to 'return' to the other side and i have $n-1$ option, And then return again and i have $n-1$ options... and so on.

So my intuition said $(n!)^2$ but actually the correct answer is  $\frac{(n!)^2}{2n}$, I don't understand where the $2n$ came from. It seems like i counted something wrong, But what is it?

Comment: Because getting from the "right side to the left side" is just as coming from the "left side to the right side". There are n nodes in each side, so you divide by 2n for each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the answer assumes that a cycle has no "start" and "end" and no "direction". In detail, the cycle $v_1, v_2, \dots ,v_{2n}$ is considered to be equivalent to the cycle $v_i, v_{i+1}, \dots, v_{2n}, v_1,\dots v_{i-1}$ for any $1\le i\le2n$. Also, the cycles $v_1, v_2, \dots ,v_{2n}$ and $v_{2n}, v_{2n-1}, \dots ,v_1$ are considered to be equivalent.
So since $2(n!)^2$ counts the number of cycles without equivalencies, there are $\frac{2(n!)^2}{2 \cdot 2n}=\frac{(n!)^2}{2n}$ cycles when considering them.